# asynchronous message thread using ZMQ

Tags: asynchronous, message, zeromq

i am communicating with an external device via a uart interface. The device will respond to commands (synchronous) but it can also send asynchronous messages when an event happens.

My plan is to create a receiver function in a separate thread that will handle the asynchronous messages, and if it is not asynchronous then publish it via a zmq publisher socket with the message ID as topic.
Then in the main thread i can send a command, create a subscriber socket and subscribe to the message ID topic and wait for the reply to arrive.

My question is if this a good approach ? It feels like a lot of overhead to create and destroy a subscriber socket with every command send ? Is there a better approach to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

A lot will depend on what else it is your main thread is going to do.

- If you need ZMQ anyway for other purposes, then there's a much simpler way you can do this (without the extra thread).
- If you don't need ZMQ as such, then there's still a simplification that removes the other thread, but you'd be replacing ZMQ with calls to functions like `select()`, or `epoll()`.
- And, if having an event loop handler running calling ZMQ's `zmq_poll()` or `select()` or `epoll()` is not what you want in your main thread, then a separate thread (much as you've envisaged) communicating with the main thread is the way to go.

**1) ZMQ Polling In the Main Thread**

The simplication is that zmq's poller (it's `reactor`, in Actor-model jargon) can wait not only for zmq sockets, but other file descriptors too (such as the file descriptor for your serial port). You've not said with operating system you're on - this won't work on Windows. So your main thread's loop would be something like:

```
loop
{
    zmq_poll(other_sockets, serial port fd, and timeout)
    if (active socket == serial port fd)
    {
        read data from serial port
        assemble complete message from device
        process message
        // "process message" could mean, send it out via another zmq socket to somewhere else
    }
    else if (active socket == other socket)
    {
        // (suppose that a command on this socket needs to be passed on to the device)
        read message from active socket
        write message content to serial port 
    }
    else if (zmq poll timed out)
    {
        // (suppose that, if nothing's happened, we need to send another command to the device, or do other thing
        generate device command message
        write device command message to serial port
        do other tasks
    }
}
for ever;
```

The interesting thing about this approach is that there's no difference between the synchronous reply from the device, and an asynchronous message from it; sure, the synchronous reply will arrive soon after you've sent the command that prompted it, but you'd be handling it in the same way as the async message. Quite neat eh?

**2) Some Other Poller in the Main Thread**

If you like this approach, but then aren't really using zmq as such (e.g. because you don't actually have any external zmq sockets to connect to), then you can replace the use of zmq entirely and just fall back to the underlying `select()` or `epoll()` (instead of the call to `zmq_poll()`). That will wait for any old file descriptor too.

**3) Can't Have a Poller in the Main Thread**

Lastly, if you can't have a `zmq_poll()` loop as shown in your main thread (nor a `select()` or `epoll()`), then you are back to something like you were originally thinking, having a secondary thread.

In that case, your secondary thread would look like the above pseudo code, and the "other socket" would be the connection from the main thread. In the main thread, you'd just use calls to `zmq_send()` to send a command to this secondary thread, which sends it through the UART's fd. The main thread will occassionally have to call `zmq_recv()` to see if anything has been sent back by the secondary thread. If it doesn't check with zmq_recv() often enough, unread messages will start accumulating in ZMQ's internal buffers.

This model avoids your main thread and secondary thread both trying to interact with the serial port file descriptor, which would get very messy very quickly.

**GUI Integration**

You can also fully integrate the ZMQ connection to the secondary thread into whatever GUI framework you may or may not have in your main thread.

Quite a few GUI frameworks allow you to specify a file descriptor which, when ready to read, equates to a GUI event (i.e. the GUI event loop handler is also calling `select()` or `epoll()`). ZMQ is very friendly to such things, because there's a zmq library call that will return a file descriptor that (if you listen to it) will become ready to read when a zmq socket has become ready to read (the ZMQ guys have really thought of a lot of useful things). Or if you prefer, you could simply get that GUI event loop poller to poll on the serial port file descriptor directly (i.e. the GUI's poller is another poller for solution 2) above).

Not all GUI frameworks like the idea of incorporating waiting for a file descriptor into their event loops, but someone will definitely have  way of getting it to wait for ZeroMQ sockets. Windows is notoriously bad in this regard, but it's perfectly possible to have Windows GUI event handlers cued up waiting for ZMQ messages and raising events for the GUI to respond to when one arrives.

**Splitting Apart the Main and Secondary Thread Completely**

There's no particular reason for your main thread and secondary thread to be either in the same process, or in the same machine, or written in the same language (so long as they can understand each other's messages). The secondary thread can be like a "device server", reachable via ZMQ, and the main thread can be something else completely.

This is one of the very nice things about ZeroMQ. It's supported by a ton of languages, across a lot of platforms. You can get a lot of advantages from exploiting that.

Anyway, I hope some of that helps!

Comment: Thanks Bazza. I was planning to implement this in a separate device driver class, so i have no direct knowledge on how the main loop will be implemented. Reading your comments i realize maybe it is indeed better to create a polling loop and leave it up to my user code to run this in a separate thread or process, as suggested in your last paragraph. Thanks again for the insights.

Comment: @Jan , You're very welcome. Good luck, I hope it goes well :-)